# Site move but old site still being shown

Tags: iis

We have moved our site to a new server about a week ago. (we kept the same domain name)

We set the TLL to a very short period of time before we moved.

On the old server i put up a page that we had moved server.

NOW, i am still getting reports that people are seeing the old server message over a week later. What have i done wrong? how can i tell the old site to redirect to the new site?

As it stands we have now redirected to a sub domain. which does not really work because the whole site runs under HTTPS and the redirect subdomain is not under HTTPS.

EDIT - further question: am i messing things up by keeping the old server alive with a working web page? If the site at the old ip was dead would that force a new DNS look up?

Comment: If the new server is on a new IP Address you will have to change the DNS to point to the new server ip. Go to the config pages of your old site and change the DNS record to point to the new ip.

Comment: I have been on to my provider and these have been changed. I go to the correct site no problem. but some people do not. One guy who has a MAC was going to the wrong page. i got him to clear his DNS cache and his safari now goes to the correct page. But his Firefox on the same machine does not.

Comment: Firefox has its own DNS cache I believe. Clearing it may be as simple as doing an F5 or CTRL F5. Not sure what to do on a MAC.

Comment: Firefox is a nightmare. And F5 did not work. We had to reset firefox. There is an add-on to clear the dns which just goes to show what an effort it is.